# UTF 8 doesn't work

Tags: php

I use utf8_encode and it doesn't returns letters like "ě,á,í,ř"...

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
define("ENCRYPTION_KEY", "!@#$%^&*");
$string = "ěčřžýáíéě"; //

function encrypt($pure_string, $encryption_key) {
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,MCRYPT_RAND);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, utf8_encode($pure_string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return $encrypted_string;
}
?>
```

What's the problem? Thanx

Comment: What are you expecting it to return and why are you expecting it to return that?

Comment: @GordonM 
I need to return sentence like "Dveře jsou skleněné".
With letters like "ř" etc...

Comment: And what are you getting instead?

Comment: @AndyIbanez 
Anything, it shows nothing